# Unable to connect socket on Treeline

Tags: socket.io, sails.js, treeline

I have this inside a view:

```
io.socket.on('message', function(response){
  if (response.verb === 'created') {
    console.log('connected');
  }
});
```

Also I have created a model called 'message', and an API rest for it.

Do you know what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treeline doesn't use the same built-in pubsub methods that Sails does.  It's possible that those may be incorporated in the future, but at present we're erring on the side of "don't include things that can't be turned off".  So if you want to notify the client about a new `message` model creation, you'll do it by adding a machine from the **Sockets** pack to your route.  The easiest one to test with is `send to all`, aka "blast" in Sails--it will send a message to every connected socket.